# How to sum numbers from a text file

Tags: arrays, vb.net, text

I'm trying to read "sales" from a text file and sum them all up to display a total sales in a box on my application. I'm doing this via a 2-D array. I have different "troops" and their selling things. So I select a troop enter the sale amount, and click add, which writes to a file. How do I read and sum up the total sales of all troops?

This is what I have so far:

```
 Private Sub addButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addButton.Click
    If salesTextBox.Text = String.Empty Then
        'display error message for invalid amount
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid amount.", "No entry",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter
        Dim troop As String = troopComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString
        Dim sales As Integer

        Integer.TryParse(salesTextBox.Text, sales)

        outFile = IO.File.AppendText("troopsales.txt")
        'write to file
        outFile.WriteLine(troop & ", " & sales)
        'close file
        outFile.Close()
    End If

    'reset focus & defaults
    salesTextBox.Focus()
    troopComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub


Private Sub displayButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles displayButton.Click
    If IO.File.Exists("troopsales.txt") Then

        Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader
        Dim testRead As String
        Dim t105Sales, t216Sales, t256Sales, t316Sales, t400Sales, t456Sales, t566Sales, t688Sales As Integer
        Dim totalSales As Integer
        inFile = IO.File.OpenText("troopsales.txt")

        Do Until inFile.Peek = -1
            testRead = inFile.ReadLine
            If testRead.Contains("105") Then
                t105Sales += totalSales
            ElseIf testRead.Contains("216") Then
                t216Sales += totalSales
            ElseIf testRead.Contains("256") Then
                t256Sales += totalSales
            ElseIf testRead.Contains("316") Then
                t316Sales += totalSales
            ElseIf testRead.Contains("400") Then
                t400Sales += totalSales
            ElseIf testRead.Contains("456") Then
                t456Sales += totalSales
            ElseIf testRead.Contains("566") Then
                t566Sales += totalSales
            ElseIf testRead.Contains("688") Then
                t688Sales += totalSales
            End If
        Loop
        inFile.Close()

        totalLabel.Text = totalSales.ToString()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Source file Invalid.", "No entry",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how I distinguish the sales or read the sales.

A sample from the text file would be:

`105, 100
256, 300
105, 10
216, 20
316, 60
400, 120
456, 240
688, 160
256, 10
105, 30
400, 100
256, 200`

The numbers on the left are the troop numbers, and on the right are the sales. I need to sum and display the total sales when I click display.

Comment: Do you HAVE to use a 2-d array or are you open to alternative suggestions?

Comment: @PaulIshak I can either use Parallel or 2-d arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing it this way:

```
    Dim troopsales = _
        File _
            .ReadAllLines("D:\Users\James\Temporary\troopsales.txt") _
            .Select(Function(x) x.Split({","c, " "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) _
            .GroupBy(Function(x) x(0), Function(x) Integer.Parse(x(1))) _
            .Select(Function(x) New With {.TroopNum = x.Key, .Sales = x.Sum()})
```

From your sample data I get this result:

[image: result]

Comment: c# answer for a vb question

Comment: I don't mean to be a stickler :-), not everyone knows c#

Comment: @PaulIshak - No, that's absolutely fair enough. I don't often make that mistake, but it's good to be picked up on it.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, the first number of each line is the troop, and all others are sales. Based on that you can use `File.ReadAllLines` static method to read your text file into an array of strings. Then use a `foreach` loop to iterate the array and send
 each string to a method thal will `spilt` it by a comma (`,`) and sum up all the elements of the array except the first. 
This will give you the sum for each troop. You can sum the results of this method for the total sum of sales.

Comment: I understand, but I'm not sure where to insert the `File.ReadAllLines` method, or how to add what is being split.

Comment: When I wrote this answer I was using my cellphone to do it. Now that I see the sample data in a normal PC browser, it seems different. Enigmativity's answer seems to do exactly what you asked for.